# Difference between 32 and 64 bit python version of exe

Tags: python, pyinstaller

There is a script that should run on 32 and 64 bit windows 7.

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2019' in position 103-104 :character maps to <undefined> (From exe console)
```

Script works both using python 3.4 x64 and x86 (they are in separate folders), but when I create exe using pyinstaller `py -m Pyinstaller script.py` 64 bit version works fine, and x86 crashes with this error.
I separately installed pyinstaller for 86 and 64 folders using pip.

decoding/overwriting in script:

```
non_bmp_map = dict.fromkeys(range(0x10000, sys.maxunicode + 1), 0xfffd)

info_non_bmp = str(info).translate(non_bmp_map)

writer.writerows(ast.literal_eval(info_chat_non_bmp))
```

info - data selected from sqlite3 database.

Are there any decoding differences in bit versions that can cause this error?

Comment: Solved. Still don't know why, but error was not in this part of code. I'm calling info 2 times, one - info[0] and full info to write into csv. Calling info[0] in executable is trying  to change ' to \u2019 while printing and writing. So script crashes

Answer (score 0):

The output of PyInstaller is specific to the active operating system and the active version of Python. This means that to prepare a distribution for:

- different OS
- different version of Python
- 32-bit or 64-bit OS

you run PyInstaller on that OS, under that version of Python. The Python interpreter that executes PyInstaller is part of the bundle, and it is specific to the OS and the word size.

Have you tried your .exe 32bit file in 32bit os ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using both versions of Pyinstaller in a 64bit system there is a problem you must take care of. PyInstaller would search your current environment and pick the Windows redistribute DLLs from the current environment which is wrong for 32bit versions. You need to provide the correct version by replacing DLL files like `vcruntime140.dll` from `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist\x86\Microsoft.VC140.CRT` and put them in Pyinstaller X86 directory in `C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\pyinstaller\bincache01_py37_32bit` and then rebuild your executable.

Comment: I've tried to create exe on 32bit machine using x86 python - same error, seems to be error somewhere in python. And it's weird, that python has error on \u2019.

Comment: First, try to generate executable as a dir, not a stand-alone and double check that the `python3.dll` is the right version if it is not trying to replace it with correct one from python directory.

Comment: You mean dist/build under dir? Btw, I'm running exe from dist folder and there is python34.dll, in python - python3.dll they should be the same?

Comment: No, you should create your exe with `pyinstaller app.py` not with `-F` option to create output as a whole directory with all files not a single large executable file.